# SoundCloud python api and GAE upload larger sounds

Tags: python, api, google-app-engine, soundcloud

I've been testing the SoundCloud Python API and it was working great with smaller files (< 1MB).  Now, I'm trying to upload larger files (5MB+) and I'm getting errors.

Here's the code:

```
import soundcloud
client = soundcloud.Client(
        client_id = app.config['SOUNCLOUD_CLIENT_ID'] ,
        client_secret= app.config['SOUNCLOUD_CLIENT_SECRET'],
        username= app.config['SOUNCLOUD_CLIENT_USERNAME'],
        password= app.config['SOUNCLOUD_CLIENT_PASSWORD'])
try:
    track = client.post('/tracks', track={
              'title':  request.form['song_title'],
              'sharing': 'public',
              'asset_data': blob_reader})
except Exception, e:
               logging.info(xstr(e))
```

Here's the error logs:

```
INFO     2014-09-05 18:29:27,199 connectionpool.py:657] Starting new HTTPS connection (1): api.soundcloud.com

INFO     2014-09-05 18:29:39,863 views.py:2308] HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.soundcloud.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /tracks.json (Caused by <class 'google.appengine.dist27.gae_override.httplib.HTTPException'>: Deadline exceeded while waiting for HTTP response from URL: https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks.json)

INFO     2014-09-05 18:29:39,914 recording.py:665] Saved; key: __appstats__:064700, part: 157 bytes, full: 222910 bytes, overhead: 0.004 + 0.050; link: http://localhost:8080/_ah/stats/details?time=1409941764737

INFO     2014-09-05 18:29:39,926 module.py:640] default: "POST /scimageupload HTTP/1.1" 200 19
```

Answer (score 1):

How long is the request taking before you get that error? Google App Engine cuts off requests that take longer than a certain number of seconds (that "Deadline exceeded" error, see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/deadlineexceedederrors) for more info).

You'll probably need to move the uploading step outside of the web request. Here are three methods GAE gives you for doing that:

- Scheduled tasks (cron):

  - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron
- Task queue:

  - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/
- Background threads:

  - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Background_threads

Comment: Thanks.  It's really quick.  Around 15 seconds and it gets that error.  I've used task queues before and might try this in one to see if it's any better, but I think it has something to do with the HTTPSConnectionPool.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this one by using the deferred task queue mechanism...

In the exception handler, I just added a call to:
      deferred.defer(sound_cloud_upload_defer, band_id, blob_key, song_title,_queue="sc-upload-queue",_countdown=5)

Then, created a sound_cloud_upload_defer function that runs on a separate queue and has a better timeout.